# PHP delete from file

Tags: php, file-io

Hey guys, I've searched around and nothing is *quite* what I need, I am horrible with PHP thus far.

Basically, I have a text file serving as a database.

Each line has the form:

```
id|lat|lng|details
```

where:

`id` is a unique integer, `lat` and `lng` are float and `details` is a string.

I have a client page (locked under user-pass) in which the user enters the unique id and a PHP script should delete the line in the file which has that unique id.

How do I accomplish this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

This is a very, very bad idea. Any simple way to solve this will be horribly racy. Any complete way will leave you wanting to use a real database.

If you insist on continuing, the way to do this is to copy every *other* line to a new file, then rename the new file back into place.

Comment: +1.  To clarify slightly, by "racy", Ignacio almost certainly means "prone to race conditions": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#File_systems

Answer (score 0):

say the user id is "1" from user input

```
$input="1";
$data = file("file");
$matches = preg_grep("/^".$input."\|/",$data,PREG_GREP_INVERT);
print_r($matches);
```

`$matches` contains the lines you want. Use [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) or fopen()/fwrite() etc to output to file